# How to create GEO-IP database configmap for NGINX ingress controller?

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, geoip, geoip2

I have a set of IP addresses (Private IPs). I want to create a custom geo-ip database. How can this be done?

For example:
10.0.0.0/16 - Asia Region
10.0.1.0/16 - Aus Region